# Getting the text from a div to be an input value of a field

Tags: jquery, html

I have a telephone field `<input id="phone" type="tel">` where the user can input his telephone number and this number together with the country code is displayed into a div `<h2>Result</h2>`. I am now in turn trying to get this number displayed into a div  to be the input value of a hidden field.

I have managed to get the telephone number however I am not able to get the country code into the hidden field as well.

```js
var input = $("#phone"),
output = $("#output");

input.intlTelInput({
  nationalMode: true,
  utilsScript: "https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
});

// listen to "keyup", but also "change" to update when the user selects a country
input.on("keyup change", function() {
  var intlNumber = input.intlTelInput("getNumber");
  if (intlNumber) {
    output.text("International: " + intlNumber);
  } else {
    output.text("Please enter a number below");
  }
});

$("#phone").change(function(){
  $("#field2").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Result</h2>
<div id="result">
  <p id="output">Please enter a number below</p>
  <input id="phone" type="tel">
</div>
Hidden: <input id="field2">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31fhLzmp/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe using the plugin method will help ?!

```
$("#phone").change(function(){
  $("#field2").val(input.intlTelInput("getNumber"));
});
```